# How to bind the same handler to multiple events with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Just wondering if there are ways to simplify the following script...Thanks for the help.

```
$('#right-arrow').live('click', function(){
        removt();
        callAjaxToCheck();
        show = true;
})

$('#tab').click(function(){
   removeTut();
   callAjaxToCheck();
   show = true;

})

$('left-arrow').live('click', function(){
        removeT();
        callAjaxToCheck();
        show = true;
})
```

Comment: I don't see an `if` statement.

Comment: Title edited to better show the intent of the question as well as help other people searching for such advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Always include semicolons in your code.**  (You're missing them after the `})` lines).

I think the cleanest way to do it is to make a separate function:

```
function doStuff() {
    removeTut();
    callAjaxToCheck();
    showTutorial = true;
}

$('#eplanner-view-range-right-arrow').live('click', doStuff);
$('#lesson-search-tab').click(doStuff);
$('#eplanner-view-range-left-arrow').live('click', doStuff);
```

Of course, you should use a more descriptive function name than `doStuff`.

Comment: doStuff is a perfectly legitimate function name, so it foo(), blah(), and jfdklsfjaksdf()

Comment: @invertedSpear Those are all terrible function names. Yes, they're technically legitimate, but making these decisions just based on what is technically legitimate is a proven mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

```
$('#eplanner-view-range-right-arrow,#lesson-search-tab,#eplanner-view-range-left-arrow').live('click', function(){
   removeTut();
   callAjaxToCheck();
   showTutorial = true;
});
```

Comment: This call to `.live` uses a delegated event for all elements, whereas the original code didn't.

Comment: s/he wants to bind to live in some cases and click in others.

Comment: @invertedSpear: But since they are all IDs (and thus unique), it's fine to delegate them all.

Comment: @jnylen: It makes no difference in this case.

Answer (score 2):

```
var func = function() {
    "use strict";
    removeTut();
    callAjaxToCheck();
    showTutorial = true;
};

$("#parent").on("click", "#eplanner-view-range-right-arrow, #eplanner-view-range-left-arrow", func);
$("#lesson-search-tab").click(func);
```

Changed `.live()` to [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) as `.live()` is deprecated as of jQuery version 1.7+. If you're running an older version of jQuery don't change `.live()`.

Comment: This may not be quite the same.  `.live` made the event delegated, this doesn't.

Comment: Not really.. since theres still no delegation

Comment: @wirey Made a mistake after I edited again and rewrote a couple of things, should be good now.